# Drupal 7 - Notice: Undefined index: und in include()

Tags: php, drupal

I'm getting this error:
**Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 24 of /home/cliffdwellerproductions/dev.cliffdwellerdigital.com/Dahl/sites/all/themes/basic/templates/node--page2.tpl.php).**

the code is:

```
if ($node->field_body_left !== NULL) : 
$text = trim($node->field_body_left['und']['0']['value']);
else:
$text = '';
```

Please help, as I haven't been able to define the variable...

Alf

Comment: please post drupal questions at [http://drupal.stackexchange.com]

Answer (score 2):

Your $node->field_body_left variable is existent but it doesn't have an 'und' element.

Comment: If I remove ['und'] - $text = trim($node->field_body_left['0']['value']);

I still get an error, and if I remove all the variables:

trim($node->field_body_left);

I get an Array error.

How should I code it?

Thanks.

Comment: Because $node->field_body_left doesn't have a 0. Try to call var_dump($node->field_body_left); before your if and you will see what is inside the $node->field_body_left variable.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're attempting to check for an empty field, but you're using `$field_body_left!==null` which will only be false if the variable is literally `null`. When a drupal field is present but empty, it's usually equal to `array()`. Use `!=` instead of `!==`, and then it will correctly detect both null variables and empty arrays and move on.

--

Extra info: If the variable had a value, its structure would be:

```
$field_body_left = array(
    'und' => array(
        0 => array (
             'value' => YOURVALUE
        )
    )
)
```

But since it doesn't have a value, its structure is:

```
$field_body_left = array()
```

Comment: I was focused on pointing out the difference between `!==` and `!=`. But you're right, isset() is a more appropriate way to do that.